# How a new validator get last state in Solana?

Tags: solana-program, validator, solana-cli, solana-test-validator, consensus

I like to join Solana mainnet as a validator and participate in consensus. As a result, I was reading about Solana and the steps to run a validator during the last few weeks.

I generally understood how Solana is working; however, I couldn't grasp how a new validator connects to the cluster and how this new validator gets the last state of the ledger. I am afraid to get the last state from a malicious validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All validators connect to the network through gossip. Each cluster (devnet, testnet, mainnet-beta) has known entrypoints that provide a gateway to participating in the network.

New validators are able to join the network by downloading snapshots from other nodes. Snapshots contain the state of all accounts on the cluster at a given slot; with a snapshot downloaded, a validator has the account state established and is able to begin replaying blocks. Typically once a node is up and running, it is more efficient to restart from your own snapshots than to continually redownload them from other nodes.

There are several protections against getting a snapshot from malicious actors:

- In the validator args, you can specify [known validators](https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-start#known-validators) to ensure that you only download a snapshot from validators you know/trust.
- If you do happen to obtain a bad snapshot from a malicious actor, your validator will very quickly fail to align on consensus with the rest of the network. If this happens, you can simply delete the snapshot, remove the validator that provided the faulty snapshot from known validators, and then get a snapshot from another node.

In general, a malicious actor has little financial incentive to provide faulty snapshots. On the other hand, other validators can become aware of a node acting maliciously and sanction it (ie block network traffic from that node).